# Maximum per partition

Tags: mysql, sql, hive

Tell me how to correctly compose a query so that the following records are displayed, as in the example.
I have a partition by id_1 and id_2 and I only take entries with the maximum operdate.

```
select a.* 
from (select t1.*,
       rank() over (partition by id_1,id_2 order by operdate desc) rn
      from table1 t1)
where a.rn=1
```

And I need to display the maximum end_circulation in the partition for these records. I understand how to do it.

```
select a.*
from (select t1.*,
       rank() over (partition by id_1,id_2 order by operdate desc) rn,
       max(end_circulation) over(partition by id_1,id_2) max_end_circulation
      from table1 t1)
where a.rn=1
```

But I need that if there is at least one NULL in end_circulation, then NULL is also set in max_end_circulation. How to do it right?

| id_1 | id_2 | end_circulation | operdate | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2123 | 6 | 2021-06-07 00:00:00 | 2021-03-04 | 1 |
| 2123 | 6 | 2021-05-05 00:00:00 | 2021-02-01 | 2 |
| 3222 | 3 | 2021-06-07 00:00:00 | 2021-01-01 | 1 |
| 3222 | 3 | NULL | 2020-12-11 | 2 |

RESULT:

| id_1 | id_2 | end_circulation | operdate | rn | max_end_circulation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2123 | 6 | 2021-06-07 00:00:00 | 2021-03-04 | 1 | 2021-06-07 00:00:00 |
| 3222 | 3 | 2021-06-07 00:00:00 | 2021-01-01 | 1 | NULL |

Comment: `RANK()` in CTE then `where rn=1` in outer query.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate additional has_null flag and use in the CASE expression:

```
select ...
       case when has_null=1 then NULL else max_end_circulation end as max_end_circulation

from
(
select t1.*,
       rank() over (partition by id_1,id_2 order by operdate desc) rn,
       max(end_circulation) over(partition by id_1,id_2) max_end_circulation
       max(case when end_circulation is null then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by id_1,id_2) has_null
from table1 t1
)s
where rn=1
```

One more approach is to convert NULLs to string 'NULL' and later convert it back. 'NULL' string is greater than any date and will be picked by max().

```
select ...
       case when max_end_circulation = 'NULL' then NULL else max_end_circulation end as max_end_circulation

from
(
select t1.*,
       rank() over (partition by id_1,id_2 order by operdate desc) rn,
       max(coalesce(end_circulation,'NULL')) over(partition by id_1,id_2) max_end_circulation
from table1 t1
)s
where rn=1
```